# Listview Item is overflow on Top of layout when scrolling

Tags: flutter, tabs

My listview widget is overflowed over another widget like the below screen.

[image: image_impgur]

Here is my full code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:propsoft/utils/dotted_decor.dart';
import '../../utils/app_theme.dart';
import '../../widget/elevated_icon_button_widget.dart';
import '../../widget/helper_utils.dart';
import '../../widget/label_widget.dart';
import 'create_user_logic.dart';

class CreateUserPage extends GetView<CreateUserLogic> {
  final logic = Get.find<CreateUserLogic>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppbar(),
      body: SafeArea(child: getBodyDetails()),
    );
  }

  Widget getBodyDetails() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        getSearchWidget(),
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [getTabBar(), getTabVarView()],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppTheme.colors.black)),
      labelColor: AppTheme.colors.black,
      unselectedLabelColor: AppTheme.colors.gray,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      tabs: const [
        Tab(text: "Users"),
        Tab(
          text: 'Status',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getTabVarView() {
    return Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
          children: [
            usersList(),
            const Center(
              child: Text("Status"),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  Widget usersList() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: DottedDecoration(
                          color: AppTheme.colors.darkBlue, shape: Shape.circle),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: AppTheme.colors.darkBlue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    PLabel(
                      text: "Invite New Users",
                      enumFontWeight: PSFontWeight.bold,
                      textColor: AppTheme.colors.darkBlue,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        margin:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            PIconButton(
                              backgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.lightBlue,
                              icon: const PLabel(
                                fontSize: 22,
                                text: "HT",
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 16,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: const [
                                PLabel(text: "My Contact List"),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4,
                                ),
                                PLabel(text: "Activated"),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 10,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getSearchWidget() {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                  controller: controller.searchController,
                  onChanged: (query) {
                    controller.filterSearchResult(query);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    labelText: "Search for a user",
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  AppBar customAppbar() {
    return AppBar(
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: PLabel(
                    text: "Save",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    textColor: AppTheme.colors.darkBlue,
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: getSVGImage("assets/images/cross.svg"),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        ),
        leadingWidth: 40,
        title: const PLabel(
          text: "Users & Group",
          fontSize: 22,
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.white,
        elevation: 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on your code....its work fine only...

Things changed... instead of PLabel Widget I have used Text Widget and Instead of PIconButton Widget I have used normal Icon Widget.... take my code as reference only...because I have changed your icons because of not having getSVGImage package and some other package.. And attaching image for your reference

[image]

```
Working example:

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppbar(),
      body: SafeArea(child: getBodyDetails()),
    );
  }

  Widget getBodyDetails() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        getSearchWidget(),
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [getTabBar(), getTabVarView()],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getTabBar() {
    return const TabBar(
      indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black)),
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: "Users"),
        Tab(
          text: 'Status',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getTabVarView() {
    return Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
          children: [
            usersList(),
            const Center(
              child: Text("Status"),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  Widget usersList() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.black12,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Invite New Users",
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        margin:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                              icon : const Icon(
                                Icons.home,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {  },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 16,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: const [
                                Text("My Contact List"),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4,
                                ),
                                Text("Activated"),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 10,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getSearchWidget() {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                  // controller: controller.searchController,
                  // onChanged: (query) {
                  //   controller.filterSearchResult(query);
                  // },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    labelText: "Search for a user",
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  AppBar customAppbar() {
    return AppBar(
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    "Save",
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.book),
          onPressed: () {
            // Get.back();
          },
        ),
        leadingWidth: 40,
        title: const Text(
          "Users & Group",
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0);
  }
```